# How to simulate a button click in Delphi FMX.TWebbrowser?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I want to automate login to a website.
The application is cross-platform, therefore I use Firemonkey.

The solutions for the old TWebbrowser unfortunately, don't work anymore.

And I don't know how to click buttons, fill in forms, read data with FMX.TVWebbrowser.

How to do it?

Comment: Why use a browser? Can't you just do this using Indy or some other comms library?

Comment: What do you mean with "Indy or some other comms library" ?

What I would need would be Selenium Webdriver for Delphi, but this is not available so far.

The problem is the Firemonkey part. For the VCL TWebbrowser I have a working solution.
But thats not crossplatform.

Comment: I did something similar (though only implemented clicks on elements) that is cross-platform in terms of Windows and macOS, however it meant having to implement the APIs on those platforms. I could do the same for iOS and Android, however I don't have a need for those, and it would mean having to go through the same process for each platform (iOS has UIWebView as opposed to macOS' NSWebView)